# MFC - Setting focus on dynamic toolbar and then pressing Enter key does application close

Tags: mfc

I have a toolbar which is created by code(dynamically using CToolBarCtrl).
Then I add some buttons in it.
Now, by running application, it shows that toolbar along with its buttons.
After that I use TAB to set on focus to one of the button in toolbar which is working fine.
Not If I press Enter Key, My whole application gets close.

Any Idea about this problem ?

Comment: Have you done any debugging?  If so, what have you tried?

Comment: If your app is `CDialog`-based then, regardless of focus, `ENTER` will close the dialog. This is default behaviour. If this is the case then you will need to override `CDialog::OnOK()` and do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have got the answer for sure, but I want to post an answer for future purpose.

```
BOOL CClassName::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN))            //getting enter key pressed
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```